# Mac software to view security camera footage from Bunker Hill 61229?

Tags: osx, video

I'm looking for software that will let me view security camera footage from a [Bunker Hill DVR](http://www.harborfreight.com/8-channel-surveillance-dvr-with-4-cameras-and-mobile-monitoring-capabilities-61229.html).

It came with a CD with software on it, but:

- I'm pretty sure it's Windows software, AKA useless to me
- It was on a tiny CD. I stupidly stuffed it in my MacBook Pro's CD drive and had a great deal of fun getting it out.

From what I can read on the subject (there isn't much), the DVR will export to .264 format. I'd like to have it in a common format so I can use tools like ffmpeg on it.

So, here's what I want:

- Convert the .264 to .mp4 or .avi, something useful
- Must run on OS X
- Ideally work to pull the files off the DVR. Otherwise, if anyone has directions on how to get the files off the DVR that would be much appreciated!

Alternatively, I would accept the software that came on the DVD - *if* it runs on OS X Yosemite.